# Promise returning undefined result to callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mariadb

I'm having issues with getting the result of a callback function. Below is the async function that I'm calling

```
const utils = {
sendQuery: async function(query){
        // Receives a query and returns raw results
        // Query is using default database specified by pool
        // Returns a Promise 
        let conn;
        try {
            conn = await pool.getConnection();
            let queryString = query;
            let rows = await conn.query(queryString);
            let results = (this.formatResults(rows));
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        } catch(err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        } finally {
            if (conn) return conn.end();
        }
}

module.exports = {
       'utils': utils
}
```

the console log above returns the expected result.

and below is the function that calls the above

```
const db = require('../private/db');

    db.utils.sendQuery(queryString).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err=>{
        throw res.render('error', {'error': err.stack});
    })
```

the console log above returns undefined and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is this part `if (conn) return conn.end();`.

Whenever you are using `finally`, it will override any previous `return`, `break`, `continue` or `throw` that happens either in the stated `try` or `catch` blocks.

To fix your issue you should do like so:

```
const utils = {
sendQuery: async function(query){
        // Receives a query and returns raw results
        // Query is using default database specified by pool
        // Returns a Promise 
        let conn;
        try {
            conn = await pool.getConnection();
            let queryString = query;
            let rows = await conn.query(queryString);
            let results = (this.formatResults(rows));
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        } catch(err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        } finally {
            if (conn) conn.end();
        }
}

module.exports = {
       'utils': utils
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: [Here's a good read on the topic](https://dev.to/annarankin/finally-in-promises--trycatch-2c44)

Comment: Oh wow this works!!!! Thank you. I learned something new today. That part of the code I took from the  mariadb driver nodejs documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, just return `results` instead of `resolve(results)`. Your function is already async and no promise object is created here.
And just throw `err` instead of `reject(err);`

And since you return in your `try`, you don't need your  `finally` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply return the result instead of calling resolve

```js
const utils = {
  sendQuery: async function(query){
        // Receives a query and returns raw results
        // Query is using default database specified by pool
        // Returns a Promise 
        let conn;
        try {
            conn = await pool.getConnection();
            let queryString = query;
            let rows = await conn.query(queryString);
            let results = (this.formatResults(rows));
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        } catch(err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        } finally {
            if (conn) return conn.end();
        }
}

module.exports = {
       'utils': utils
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for the reply. It is still not working. I tried throwing the error inside and outside the try statement just to test the catch if it will be called and it works.

Comment: Did you get the result? try simply `throw Error(err)`

Comment: Weirdly enough when I added the throw Error after the await it doesn't seem to throw the error and it runs the then on the function calling it. Wut??????

Comment: ah, missed!. you need to remove return from the `finally` block. as said in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply return or i suppose this is what you were trying to do

```
sendQuery: (query) => {
    let promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let conn;
        try {
            conn = await pool.getConnection();
            let queryString = query;
            let rows = await conn.query(queryString);
            let results = (this.formatResults(rows));
            console.log(results);
            resolve(results);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        } finally {
            if (conn) {
                conn.end();
            }
        }
    })
    return promise;
}
```